# Swift: Mask Alignment + Auto-Layout Constraints

Tags: swift, calayer, mask

I have this PNG file, which I'd like to use as a mask for a `UIView`.

[image]

The view must be:

- 20 pixels/points in from each side
- A perfect square
- Centered vertically

I set the following constraints to accomplish this:

[image]

However, it seems these constraints don't play well with masks. When these constraints and the `mask` property are set, I get the following:

[image]

but I'd like the view to look just like the mask above, except orange (The `backgroundColor` here is just for simplicity—I later add subviews that need to be masked.)

However, when no constraints are set, the `mask` seems to work properly and I get something like this (`borderColor` added for visual purposes only):

[image]

Here's my code (`viewForLayer` is a UIView I made in the storyboard):

```
    viewForLayer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    viewForLayer.layer.borderWidth = 10

    var mask = CALayer()
    mask.contents = UIImage(named: "TopBump")!.CGImage
    mask.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewForLayer.bounds.width, height: viewForLayer.bounds.height)
    mask.position = CGPoint(x: viewForLayer.bounds.width/2, y: viewForLayer.bounds.height/2)
    viewForLayer.layer.mask = mask
    viewForLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

The problem is though, that now the view isn't the right size or in the right position—it doesn't follow the rules above—"The view must be: ". **How can I have the `mask` work properly, and the auto-layout constraints set at the same time?**

Comment: Are you sure that this `viewForLayer` has the correct size?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the correct size, but I set the constraints in the storyboard, and when I run it without setting the layer's `mask` property, it's an orange square that occupies the exact same space as it does when masked, except for the fact the bottom right corner, which is, obviously, orange as well.

Comment: Try to inset the orange view with a border to see if the constraints are correct. I suspect that the orange background view is extending way pass the right boundary of the screen.

Comment: I don't see the Center X align constraint, just the Y one.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying—I didn't add a Center X align constraint because I don't think I need one given the fact that the view is inset from each side by 20. Also, adding a border, when the `mask` property is set reveals nothing. I would upload another image, but it takes up so much space I'll just describe it: the border stops and follows the curve of the mask and the rest of `viewForLayer`.

Comment: It's hard to debug visual problems when remote. One way to determine if this is an autolayout issue is to disable it and size constraints in the storyboard using inspector. If things are aligned when you disable that, then you know that's the problem.

Comment: It does indeed appear to be a constraints problem—you can see the image I added when I deleted all the constraints. But I still need the constraints, so what can I do?

Comment: Also, I just added a new view with a View for center layer = center X and used it as viewForLayer. That worked. So I would try adding this constraint on yours too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80527/discussion-between-5813-and-johndifool).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80547/discussion-between-johndifool-and-5813).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way around it. Not sure if this is the best way but here we go...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1e3N.jpg

Just make sure you change the name of the UIView class in the storyboard inspector too. Apparently, the trick is to set the mask frame for each layoutSubviews call.

```
class MaskView : UIView {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let mask = self.layer.mask {
      mask.frame = self.bounds
    }        
  }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewForLayer: MaskView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "TopBump")!.CGImage!
        let maskLayer = CALayer()
        maskLayer.contents = image
        maskLayer.frame = viewForLayer.bounds
        viewForLayer.layer.mask = maskLayer
        viewForLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        viewForLayer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        viewForLayer.layer.borderWidth = 10


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I got a weird error which I posted in our chat.

Comment: I updated the MaskView code to deal with the BAD_ACCESS case.

Comment: still working 7 years later in Swift 5 and Xcode 14.1. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it for myself. Minus the nitpicking on 'let mask = CALayer()' (it's immutable reference to an updatable object), changing the autolayout constraints of the embedded view shows the mask is aligned correctly.

```
    NSLog("\(viewForLayer.bounds.width), \(viewForLayer.bounds.height)")
```

returns 375.0, 667.0 on an iPhone 6 screen. What are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. See the edit I just made. And for the `NSLog`, on an iPhone 6, I get: 600.0, 600.0.